# Refresh Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material

So I have an Array of Objects, which gets its Data from the Session Storage and then displays the Data in an Angular Material Table. The Data in the Session Storage comes from a different Tab and are just table rows, which the user can click and store in the Session Storage.

So now my question ist, how do i refresh the Table after switching tabs?

This is the Array from the Table that is to be refreshed:

```
const EXAMPLE_DATA: CompareServerDataItems[] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("selectedServers")  || '{}');
```

Comment: The sessionStorage is isolated for each tab, so they can't communicate

Comment: Its still the same website, just a different tab in the menu.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Different tab = different session.

Comment: Maybe i havent made it clear enough:
I switch from the http://localhost:4200/home to http://localhost:4200/compare

And the data does in fact stay in the same session storage.